# retryWhen barred in VSCode

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Hello I have the retryWhen pipeable function barred in VScode, it seem like a deprecated method, do you have any idea about this:
[image]

Comment: Please post copy of code rather than an image

Comment: _"it seem like a deprecated method"_ - and indeed it is deprecated https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen Was this your question?